# Customizr Pro editing menu issue with some Woocommerce custom code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes, payment-gateway

I attempted to ask Customizr support what my code was running into, but they basically said they do not support 3rd party plugins such as Woocommerce

I needed to restrict the payment types based on what folk were buying on the site. 
For example, the Check payment type is only available for people buying lessons.

Here is the code that does this:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 
'threshold_unset_gateway_by_category' );

function threshold_unset_gateway_by_category( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
$unset = false;
$category_ids = array( 22, 21, 25, 20);
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $values ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );    
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {        
        if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ids ) ) {
            $unset = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
    if ( $unset == true ) unset( $available_gateways['cheque'] );
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

I have dug into the Customizr files but I cannot find any conflict. The Wordpress files can be a bit convoluted, so I might be barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this was much more simpler than I expected. Thank you @LoicTheAztec for the tips, I utilized Loic's code for better optimization.
The fix was to check if the user is admin

```
 if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $available_gateways;
    }
```

Then put the rest of the code in an else.
Here is the full solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'categories_unset_cheque_gateway', 99, 1 );
function categories_unset_cheque_gateway( $gateways ){
    if (is_admin()){
        return $gateways;
    }
    // BELOW define your categories in the array (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    else{
        $categories = array( 15 );
        // Loop through cart items checking for specific product categories
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
            if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
                unset( $gateways['cheque'] );
                break; // Stop the loop
            }
        return $gateways;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not made to solve your issue with Customizr, I have just revisited your code in a much more light, compact and flexible way.

I have also added a priority and the number of arguments in the `add_filter()`, and this sometimes solve strange issues…

So in this code, I use WP `has_term()` conditional function instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'categories_unset_cheque_gateway', 99, 1 );
function categories_unset_cheque_gateway( $available_gateways ){
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    // BELOW define your categories in the array (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $categories = array( 20, 21, 22, 25 );

    // Loop through cart items checking for specific product categories
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
        if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
            unset( $available_gateways['cheque'] );
            break; // Stop the loop
        }

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works *(untested with Customizr Pro)*.

Comment: This helps, but did not solve the issue, as mentioned in the question, why would suppressing certain payment gateways, now using your method, disrupt one's ability to edit the menu?

Comment: @DSMTurboAWD Sorry, but I haven't and I don't use Customizr Pro, so I can't test it (as it's a commercial theme). I hope you will find a way to solve that issue.